# overflows in size_t additions

Tags: c, integer-overflow, size-t

I like to have my code warning free for VS.NET and GCC, and I like to have my code 64-bit ready.

Today I wrote a little module that deals with in memory buffers and provides access to the data via a file-style interface (e.g. you can read bytes, write bytes, seek around etc.).

As the data-type for current read position and size I used size_t since that seems to be the most natural choice. I get around the warnings and it ought to work in 64-bit as well.

Just in case: My structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char * m_Data;
  size_t          m_CurrentReadPosition;
  size_t          m_DataSize;
} MyMemoryFile;
```

The signedness of `size_t` seems not to be defined in practice. A Google code-search proved that.

Now I'm in a dilemma: I want to check additions with `size_t` for overflows because I have to deal with user supplied data and third party libraries will use my code. However, for the overflow check I have to know the sign-ness. It makes a huge difference in the implementation.

So - how the heck should I write such a code in a platform and compiler independent way?

Can I check the signedness of `size_t` at run or compile-time? That would solve my problem. Or maybe `size_t` wasn't the best idea in the first place.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a solution for the C-language!

Comment: what version of gcc are you using? It looks like they made size_t unsigned in versions after and including 2.4

Comment: The versions I have to deal with are all over the place. I do embedded programming and sometimes I have to use compiler versions from the stone-ages.

Comment: "Signedness" is the usual word.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding the whether `size`_t is signed or unsigned and GCC (from an old GCC manual - I'm not sure if it's still there):

> There is a potential problem with the
>   `size_t` type and versions of GCC prior
>   to release 2.4. ANSI C requires that
>   `size_t` always be an unsigned type. For
>   compatibility with existing systems'
>   header files, GCC defines `size_t` in
>   `stddef.h` to be whatever type the
>   system's `sys/types.h` defines it to
>   be. Most Unix systems that define
>   `size_t` in `sys/types.h`, define it to
>   be a signed type. Some code in the
>   library depends on `size_t` being an
>   unsigned type, and will not work
>   correctly if it is signed.
>
> The GNU C library code which expects
>   `size_t` to be unsigned is correct. The
>   definition of `size_t` as a signed type
>   is incorrect. We plan that in version
>   2.4, GCC will always define `size_t` as an unsigned type, and the
>   'fixincludes' script will massage the
>   system's `sys/types.h` so as not to
>   conflict with this.
>
> In the meantime, we work around this
>   problem by telling GCC explicitly to
>   use an unsigned type for `size_t` when
>   compiling the GNU C library.
>   'configure' will automatically detect
>   what type GCC uses for `size_t` arrange
>   to override it if necessary.

If you want a signed version of `size_t` use `ptrdiff_t` or on some systems there is a typedef for `ssize_t`.

Comment: Had to do it for my own curiosity - I found it hard to believe that GCC would disregard a pretty basic part of the standard without a decent explanation.

Answer (score 5):

`size_t` should be unsigned.

It's typically defined as unsigned long.

I've never seen it be defined otherwise. `ssize_t` is its signed counterpart.

EDIT:
GCC defines it as signed in some circumstances. compiling in ASNI C mode or std-99 should force it to be unsigned.

Comment: GCC defines size_t as signed :(

Comment: Isn't unsigned long 32 bits in 64 bit windows?  Not a good assumption for size_t.

Comment: g++ 4.2.3 defines it as unsigned.

Comment: How did this issue come up in 2008? The last version of GCC that (wrongly) defined `size_t` as signed was obsolete more than 10 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

`size_t` is an unsigned integral type, according to the C++ C standards.  Any implementation that has `size_t` signed is seriously nonconforming, and probably has other portability problems as well.  It is guaranteed to wrap around when overflowing, meaning that you can write tests like `if (a + b < a)` to find overflow.

`size_t` is an excellent type for anything involving memory.  You're doing it right.

Answer (score 2):

For C language, use [IntSafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521693(v=vs.85).aspx). Also released by Microsoft (not to be confused with the C++ library SafeInt). IntSafe is a set of C language function calls that can perform math and do conversions safely.
[updated URL for intsafe functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521693(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [safeint](http://www.codeplex.com/SafeInt). It is a class designed by Michael Howard and released as open source from Microsoft. It is designed to make working with integers where overflow is identified as a risk. All overflows are converted to exceptions and handled. The class is designed to make correct usage easy.

For example :

```
char CouldBlowUp(char a, char b, char c)
{
   SafeInt<char> sa(a), sb(b), sc(c);

   try
   {
     return (sa * sb + sc).Value();
   }
   catch(SafeIntException err)
   {
      ComplainLoudly(err.m_code);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Also safeint is used a lot internally at Microsoft in products like Office.

Ref:
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972705.aspx)

Comment: I can't use SaveInt. I'm C-only, and afaik saveint does not solve the sign-ness problem as well because it assumes the defaults from msvc.

Comment: Oh right the question was initially marked as C++. See my other answer for a C language library.

Comment: Yes - I know. Sorry about that. I edited the question to make sure I don't mislead anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand the question exactly, but maybe you can do something like:

```
temp = value_to_be_added_to;

value_to_be_added_to += value_to_add;

if (temp > value_to_be_added_to)
{
  overflow...
}
```

Since it will wrap back to lower values you can easily check if it overflowed.

Comment: What if value_to_add is negative?